# WP8 Passcode sync/access

Tags: lock-screen, password

I'm trying to assist a friend who has a Nokia Lumia 830 running WP8, and who is complaining about someone persistently telling her what her passcode is (accurately), even after she has changed it.

My question is, is there any way on WP8, perhaps through a connected Windows Live account or a malicious app or similar, for the devices lockscreen passcode to be synced, backed up, or otherwise made potentially available, and if so how can I diagnose this and turn it off?

Comment: Is this being done remotely or is the person possibly just seeing finger prints on the screen showing where your friend taps in the passcode?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do sync this in any way.

My guess is that they just do some mind tricks or read the fingerprints on the screen.

Who is this "someone"? and how does he/she guess the passcode? does he tell it in 1 go without talking to the phone owner?